# Upload and display multiple images using php?

Tags: php, image, file-upload, image-uploading, multiple-file-upload

Insert Code:

```
 <input type="hidden" name="size" value="350000">
<input type="file" name="photo">
```

Display Code:

```
 echo "<img src='/images/" . $row['photo']. "' height='150px'><br>";
```

But this only handles one photo.  Any way of doing multiple images?

Here's the php the processes the data that is inputted into the form:

```
 <?php

 //This is the directory where images will be saved
 $target = "images/";
 $target = $target . basename( $_FILES['photo']['name']);

 //This gets all the other information from the form
 $photo=($_FILES['photo']['name']);

 // Connects to your Database
 mysql_connect("localhost", "", "") or die(mysql_error()) ;
 mysql_select_db("dirtypol_election2016compariso") or die(mysql_error()) ;

 // Writes the information to the database
 mysql_query("INSERT INTO databasename (photo) VALUES ('$photo')") ;

 //Writes the photo to the server
 if(move_uploaded_file($_FILES['photo']['tmp_name'], $target)) {

 //Tells you if its all ok
 echo "The file ". basename( $_FILES['uploadedfile']['name']). " has been uploaded, and your information has been added to the directory";
 }
 else {
 //Gives and error if its not
 echo "Sorry, there was a problem uploading your file.";
 }
 ?>
```

Comment: Loop it! Use any loop statement to handle multiple images. But be more clear what you wanna do!?

Comment: the two snippets of code you have shown don't appear to work in conjunction - there is surely other code which you have omitted to show?

Comment: I updated the post with the php I am using for the processing of the data.

Answer (score 1):

- Input name must be be defined as an array i.e. name="inputName[]"
- Input element must have multiple="multiple" or just multiple In your
- PHP file use the syntax "$_FILES['inputElemName']['param'][index]"
- Make sure to look for empty file names and paths, the array might
  contain empty strings

HTML:

```
<input name="files[]" type="file" multiple="multiple" />
```

PHP:

```
<?php

include('config.php'); // my database connection is come form this file

// check files are set or not
if(isset($_FILES['files'])){

    $errors= array();
    $desired_dir="attachments/"; // replace with your directory name where you want to store images
    // getting files array
    foreach($_FILES['files']['tmp_name'] as $key => $tmp_name ){

        $file_name = $_FILES['files']['name'][$key];
        $file_size =$_FILES['files']['size'][$key];
        $file_tmp =$_FILES['files']['tmp_name'][$key];
        $file_type=$_FILES['files']['type'][$key];  
        // checking file size (because i use it)
        if($file_size > 8097152){
            $errors[]='File size must be less than 8 MB'; // change or remove it
        }       

        $filename=time().$file_name; // for creating unique file name
        if(empty($errors)==true){
            // moving files to destination
            $move=move_uploaded_file($file_tmp,$desired_dir.$filename);
            // you can direct write move_uploaded files method in bellow if condition
            if($move)
            {
                // inserting data into database
                mysql_query("INSERT into your_tablename(your_field) VALUES('$filename')"); // inserting data if file is moved
                echo "The file ".$filename." has been uploaded"; // only for debugging
            }
            else{
                echo $filename."is note uploaded"; // use this for debugging otherwise remove it
            }

        }
        else{
            echo $errors;
        }
            }
    }
    if(empty($error)){
        echo "All attachments are uploaded successfully"; // your success message/action
    }
?>
```

i am using above code for upload and insert data of multipal files and it's working smoothly. :)
Hope this helpful...

Comment: I've updated the post with the php I use for processing the data.  Can you check my php code and see how I can update or improve it?

Comment: Hey Thomas, i update my php code... check it... hope this work for you. it's working for me fine. :)